# Separating date and time from datetime format mysql

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have an event page that displays events from database. In my database, I have a column with datetime format. is there a way to only get the date or time separate from each other in a select to be displayed in PHP ?

Note : I am looking for anything default/core PHP function for this issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use this query , you will get your desired output :

```
$sql = "SELECT DATE(datecolumn) as mydate, TIME(datecolumn) as mytime FROM `tablename`";
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `date_format` function

```
SELECT date_format(dateCol, '%Y-%m-%d') as `date`,
date_format(dateCol, '%H:%i:%s') as `time` FROM tableName;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the mysql functions:

```
SELECT DATE(column), TIME(column) FROM table
```

On php-side use `date('d.m.y', $column)` and `date('H:i:s', $column)`.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL use DATE(`insertdate`), TIME(`insertdate`)

Answer (score 0):

date_format Method used for splitting date and time.

```
SELECT 
       date_format(ColumnName, '%Y-%m-%d') as Date,
       date_format(ColumnName, '%H:%i:%s') as Time
FROM  
        tableName;
```